# Kryonet packet not sent

Tags: java, kryonet

So I'm trying out kryonet, sending a custom packet, but the listener in my server can't seem to pick it up.

```
server.addListener(new Listener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void received(Connection connection, Object object) {
                System.out.println("received");
                if (object instanceof Packet) {
                        Packet p = (Packet) object;
                        System.out.println(p.name);

                }
            }
        });
```

Sending:

```
            Packet p = new Packet();
        p.name = "test";
        client.sendTCP(p);
```

Reading through other threads, I've tried using `new Thread(client).start();` instead of `client.start();`, and I've added empty constructors to my packet classes, but the client either connects, then hangs and never disconnects (if I'm using new Thread(client).start()) or connects then immediately disconnects (if I'm using client.start()). Nothing is ever printed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your listener receiving *anything*? (You've got an `if` statement there, but you haven't told us whether you're seeing "received" but not the packet name, or just nothing...)

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying - yes, nothing is being printed at all.

Comment: @Jimmt, hard to tell from the snippet of your code. Have you tried their example apps, [position sample](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet/tree/master/examples/com/esotericsoftware/kryonet/examples/position) seems reasonably simple

Comment: Is `Packet` `Serializable`? Actually, please post `Packet`.

Comment: Packet does not have to be serializable. Did you do the necessary steps to register the object, Kryo kryo = server.getKryo(); kryo.register(Packet.class); ?

Comment: I think I will post some example code I wrote a bit ago.

Comment: so much for the bounty :p

Comment: Try increasing the buffer size, I've had problem with Kryonet due to too large packet.

Answer (score 1):

These are the necessary steps to make KryoNet work:

```
Server server = new Server();
Kryo kryo = server.getKryo();
kryo.register(float[].class);
server.start();
server.bind(2300, 2301);
server.addListener(new Listener() {
    public void received(Connection connection, Object object)
    {
        if(object instanceof float[])
        {
            float[] array = (float[])object;
        } 
    }
});

Client client = new Client();
Kryo kryo = client.getKryo();
kryo.register(float[].class);
client.addListener(new Listener() {
    public void connected(Connection connection)
    {
        connection.sendTCP(new float[] {5.0f, 6.0f, 7.0f, 8.0f});
    }
});
client.start();
client.connect(5000, "127.0.0.1”, 2300, 2301);
```

Of course, you can use client.sendTCP() once you've connected to the server.
Replace the float[] with Packet, and it should work.

You don't need to mess with making threads yourself, KryoNet is already asynchronous, except for the discoverHost() method call if you use it.

EDIT: I whipped up an example project that works.

Packet.java:

```
public class Packet
{
    private String message;

    public Packet()
    {
    }

    public Packet(String message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

KryoClient.java:

```
public class KryoClient
{
    private Client client;

    public KryoClient() throws IOException
    {
        client = new Client();
        Kryo kryo = client.getKryo();
        kryo.register(float[].class);
        kryo.register(Packet.class);
        //kryo.register(String.class);
        client.addListener(new Listener() {
            public void connected(Connection connection)
            {
                //connection.sendTCP(new float[] {5.0f, 6.0f, 7.0f, 8.0f});
                connection.sendTCP(new Packet("Hello, Server! You're sexy, rawr :3"));
            }

            @Override
            public void received(Connection connection, Object object)
            {
                if (object instanceof float[])
                {
                    float[] array = (float[]) object;
                    for(float a : array)
                    {
                        System.out.println(a);
                    }
                }
                else if(object instanceof Packet)
                {
                    Packet packet = (Packet) object;
                    System.out.println("Message: " + packet.getMessage());
                    connection.sendTCP(new Packet("The packet has arrived to client."));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void disconnected(Connection arg0)
            {
                System.out.println("Server disconnected.");
            }
        });
        client.start();
        client.connect(5000, "127.0.0.1", 2305, 2306);
    }

    public Client getClient()
    {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(Client client)
    {
        this.client = client;
    }
}
```

KryoServer.java:

```
public class KryoServer
{
    private Server server;

    public KryoServer() throws IOException
    {
        server = new Server();
        Kryo kryo = server.getKryo();
        kryo.register(float[].class);
        kryo.register(Packet.class);
        //kryo.register(String.class);
        server.start();
        server.bind(2305, 2306);
        server.addListener(new Listener()
        {
            @Override
            public void connected(Connection connection)
            {
                connection.sendTCP(new Packet("Server says, connected to server."));
            }

            @Override
            public void received(Connection connection, Object object)
            {
                if (object instanceof float[])
                {
                    float[] array = (float[]) object;
                    for(float a : array)
                    {
                        System.out.println(a);
                    }
                }
                else if(object instanceof Packet)
                {
                    Packet packet = (Packet) object;
                    System.out.println("Message: " + packet.getMessage());
                    //connection.sendTCP(new Packet("The packet has arrived to server."));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void disconnected(Connection connection)
            {
                System.out.println("Client disconnected.");
            }
        });
    }

    public Server getServer()
    {
        return server;
    }

    public void setServer(Server server)
    {
        this.server = server;
    }
}
```

ClientThread.java:

```
public class ClientThread extends Thread
{
    private KryoClient client;
    private volatile boolean running;

    public ClientThread(KryoClient client)
    {
        this.client = client;
        running = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        long initTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(running)
        {
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - initTime > 1000)
            {
                initTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                client.getClient().sendTCP(new Packet("Hello from " + System.currentTimeMillis()));
                //should have used Thread.sleep(1000); instead
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopThread()
    {
        running = false;
    }
}
```

MyMain.java:

```
public class MyMain
{
    private static KryoClient kryoClient = null;
    private static KryoServer kryoServer = null;
    private static ClientThread thread = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        System.out.println("What's up, doc?");
        System.out.println("Press '1' for server.");
        System.out.println("Press '2' for client.");

        try
        {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String line = br.readLine();
            int number = Integer.parseInt(line);
            if (number == 1)
            {
                kryoServer = new KryoServer();
                System.out.println("Server started.");
            }
            else if (number == 2)
            {
                kryoClient = new KryoClient();
                System.out.println("Client started.");
                thread = new ClientThread(kryoClient);
                thread.start();
            }
            System.out.println("Press a button to exit.");
            br.readLine();

            System.out.println("Test end.");
        }
        finally
        {
            if(kryoClient != null)
            {
                kryoClient.getClient().stop();
            }
            if(kryoServer != null)
            {
                kryoServer.getServer().stop();
            }

            if (br != null)
            {
                br.close();
            }
            if (thread != null)
            {
                thread.stopThread();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And it works.

Comment: By the way, I had trouble connecting with the default ports, too - which is why I changed them to 2300 for TCP and 2301 for UDP.

Comment: For some odd reason, it works when everything is in one file like that, but when I separate into client/server classes and run the server then the client I have the original issue...

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but I made them into singleton classes, personally. There has to be SOMETHING you are missing if it doesn't work - it worked for me even cross-platform!

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the exact same methods, and you have the same things going on? Do you try to send the Packet only after the connection has been made? Try sending the Packet in the Connected callback like I did in the example.

Comment: I literally copied and pasted your client code into my client class, and server code to the server class, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you using the same ports? Are you using the right IP? Does it connect to the client? I mean, I know you don't receive the packet, but does it actually receive the Connected event? Are the ports open on the server if they are on two different devices?

Comment: Connected event is received, packet isn't. I'm still trying on my own computer (same device)

Comment: I'm guessing you are using 127.0.0.1 to connect to it, and you made sure the ports are the same. Are you using ports below 9000? I had issues with those above 10000. Did you try sending Packet in the connected callback like I posted above? That SHOULD work.

Comment: Like I said, I'm using the exact same code, the connection is registered but nothing is received when I separately run the server and then the client in different files.

Comment: By other file, do you mean other project? Or just two different source files. If you mean two different source files, then this should work as you can see.

Comment: The package for "Packet" is the same for both cases, right?

Comment: yeah, it is the same file

Comment: Did you try the example I posted in my edit? I tried it, it worked, and it has the stuff in two different files.