# RMI very slow is client and server are not in the same machine

Tags: performance, reference, rmi

i have a strange problem. I developed client-server application with Java RMI, and in the localhost work very fine, also work very well if i put the client and server on two different MacBook Pro, but work very very slowly if i try to put the client and the server on two computer that are not macbook pro. I have this problem only if i try to send a reference of the client to the server with invocation of a remote method.

This is my code

SERVER:

```
    public class Server{

      public static void main(String [] args){
          try
          {
              Server_Impl server=new Server_Impl();

              Registry reg=LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
              reg.bind("Server",server);

              if(new Scanner(System.in).nextInt()==-1){
                  System.exit(0);
              }
          }
          catch (RemoteException e){e.printStackTrace( );}
          catch (AlreadyBoundException e) {e.printStackTrace( );}
      }

  }
```

CLIENT

```
public class Client{
    public static Interfaccia_Server Server;

public static void main(String [] args){
    try{
        Registry reg=LocateRegistry.getRegistry("10.0.1.5",1099);

        Server = (Interfaccia_Server) reg.lookup("Server");

Client_Impl c= new Client_Impl(Server);
    Server.connect_client(c);
c.check_action();
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }

}
}
```

All of the code work, but very very slow if client and server are not on the same machine, or on a apple mac computer.

If i remove this line of code from the client all work very well anywhere, but i need the reference of the client in the server

```
Server.connect_client(c);
```

I have no idea about, please help me

Comment: While this isn't exactly what you're looking for, if you are using Java as both the server and the client using the same JAR, then I recommend KryoNet library for communication: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24452428/2413303 and it even has a sort of RMI replacement, more info on : https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet

Comment: If i can solve this problem without external library it would be better

Comment: Err, what does Server.connect_client *do?*

Comment: Server.connect_client(c) insert the reference c of the client into a Vector, this reference are used for the callback from server to client

Comment: You need to post the code. In your question. It's incomplete without.

Comment: I solve the problem, i modified the ip address on the etc/hosts file, and put the lan address instead the 127.0.0.1, but i want to know if it possible to obtain the same result without modify the hosts file